# Problems when upgrading from Wildfly 10 to Widlfly 11 in undertow

Tags: java, wildfly, atmosphere, undertow, wildfly-11

I have encountered 2 issues when upgrading from Wildfly 10 to 11 (Final).

Under Firefox, I get the following error;

> 2017-10-25 13:28:42,865 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-20)
>   UT005023: Exception handling request to
>   /fluid/javax.faces.resource/syntaxhighlighter.css.xhtml:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ssl is null at
>   org.wildfly.openssl.SSLImpl.getSessionId0(Native Method) at
>   org.wildfly.openssl.SSLImpl.getSessionId(SSLImpl.java:479) at
>   org.wildfly.openssl.OpenSSLEngine.getSession(OpenSSLEngine.java:871)
>   at
>   io.undertow.server.protocol.http.ALPNLimitingSSLEngine.getSession(ALPNLimitingSSLEngine.java:211)
>   at
>   io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.getSslSession(SslConduit.java:638)
>   at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.UndertowSslConn

Please see;
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-9479

and in relation to WebSockets using Atmosphere - 2.4.14;

> rieve All Personal Inventory Items Took '0' millis. 2017-10-25
>   13:26:54,718 DEBUG
>   [com.flowjob.web.backing.push.endpoint.RefreshViewEndpoint]
>   (Atmosphere-Scheduler-190) [/refresh_view] : onClose() 2017-10-25
>   13:26:54,744 DEBUG
>   [com.flowjob.web.backing.push.endpoint.RefreshViewEndpoint] (default
>   task-28) [/refresh_view] : onOpen() 2017-10-25 13:26:55,022 ERROR
>   [io.undertow.request] (default task-18) UT005023: Exception handling
>   request to
>   /fluid/primepush/user_session/ZKAen-M9wRcAFnnjsaI2wzjb0sBE80YCWPRChM-j:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1011)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1006)
>   at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest$LocalAttributes.put(AtmosphereRequest.java:589)
>   at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequestImpl.wrap(AtmosphereRequestImpl.java:1415)
>   at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:191)
>   at
>   org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:177)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>   at
>   io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:130)
>   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

Please see;
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-9480

Anyone else having issues?

Comment: Woudln't this be an issue to ask in the JBoss Mailing list or something? This doesn't seem like a question related to code specifically, moreso if the update broke anyone elses code.

Comment: I followed their instructions. Just covering the bases. The traces are also indicating that its likely to be a wildfly bug. https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HelpBugReport

Comment: Issue relating to Atmosphere was a bug in undertow (nullpointer). Ticket was updated; https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-1218